# My Procedure isn't working right. It keeps giving me an error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CHECK_BLACKLIST 
(
  P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2 
, P_ROWCOUNT OUT NUMBER 
) AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO P_ROWCOUNT FROM boe_safegaurd WHERE UPPER(employee_username) = UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME);  
END CHECK_BLACKLIST;
```

Errors

I entered joe@example.com when I ran the procedure.

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 26:
PLS-00352: Unable to access another database 'example.com'
ORA-06550: line 5, column 26:
PLS-00201: identifier 'joe@eample.com' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Process exited.
```

when I enter "joe@example.com", I get a similar error

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 27:
PLS-00201: identifier 'joe@eample.com' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. While the procedure executes correctly from SQL or PL/SQL code, somehow SQLDeveloper raises an exception when you invoke the procedure (via the green arrow) and pass anything as input that contains a "@" sign. It's either a peculiar behavior of SQL Developer or a bug.
[image: x]
But executing it directly works fine, also from SQL Developer:
[image: x]

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CHECK_BLACKLIST
(
  P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2
, P_ROWCOUNT OUT NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO P_ROWCOUNT FROM all_users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME);
END CHECK_BLACKLIST;
/

Procedure created.

set serveroutput on
declare
  r number;
begin
  CHECK_BLACKLIST('joe@example.com', r);
  dbms_output.put_line(r);
end;
/

0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The procedure works. The way you try to use it, does not. But we can not see that, because you did not post that.

SQL Developer:

[image]

This line is just wrong:

`P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME := joe@example.com;`

If you try to set P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME as `'joe@example.com'`, SQL Developer automatically adds extra quoting marks to both to the input value and the generated code, which is also wrong:

[image]

Just edit the code manually to `P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME := 'joe@example.com';` as below:

[image]

To be honest, I never use this feature of SQL Developer.

Comment: I pressed the play button in SQL Developer and entered an email as the username. That’s where these errors started appearing. It does compile

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? I am getting errors.